# Openvpn redirect-gateway def1 not working

Tags: linux, windows, debian, vpn, openvpn

I have seed multiple answers in serverfault but non of them work for me therefore i am finally posting my question here.

I have been using openvpn for years. today i stuck in a issue which i never face before. i wanted to redirect all traffic through vpn for a client however a option to redirect is notworking. i place the redirect-gateway def1 in server config and client configs individually and on both configs at same time. but nothing works.
the confusing point is that when i remove the redirect-gateway value from both config. my vpn works fine. i can ping remote network IPs with no problem. but when i use this option i fail to ping any ip on remote. or even in local network. i dont know what is going on i request you to kindly give your expert advice.

here is my server config

```
port 10640
proto tcp-server
dev tun0
ca keys/jp-ca/ca.crt
cert keys/jp-ca/openvpn-srv-key.crt
key keys/jp-ca/openvpn-srv-key.key
dh keys/jp-ca/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
crl-verify keys/jp-ca/crl.pem
cipher DES-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
status servers/jp-ovpn-srv/logs/openvpn-status.log
log-append servers/jp-ovpn-srv/logs/openvpn.log
verb 6
mute 20
max-clients 100
keepalive 10 60
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/servers/jp-ovpn-srv/ccd
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
persist-key
persist-tun
ccd-exclusive
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

and here i my client side config

```
client
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
dh dh2048.pem
cert ykhan-desktop.crt
key ykhan-desktop.key
cipher DES-CBC
verb 2
mute 20
keepalive 10 120
#comp-lzo no
persist-key
persist-tun
float
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
pull
remote 17x.xx.xx.201 3389
socks-proxy-retry
socks-proxy 127.0.0.1 447
#redirect-gateway
#route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 net_gateway
```

Can you guys please help. any hint or idea will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Yousuf

Comment: What happens if you only use `redirect-gateway` config line on client side?

Comment: Is IP forwarding and source NAT enabled? see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289307/60293, `echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
&& sysctl -p`

Comment: Thanks you for your response, Yes net is enabled. the point of notice is when i use redirect-gateway on client or server specifically or even on both. i can not ping loopback interface of Ovpn Server.  however on the otherhand when i remove redirect-gateway things start to work normal. like i can ping ovpn server loop back or other public interfaces. but the problem is this way i can not redirect all traffic through server.  One more thing i am using obfsproxy.

Comment: Show routes table on server and on client when connected with and without redirect-gateway. Also logs will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks you all for helping me out. but i think i found the problem i add this like 'route serverIP 255.255.255.255 net_gateway' and things start working.  since i was using obfsproxy i think the issue was related ot obfsproxy channel and not openvpn related issue.